# AWS Redshift Transaction memory limits for my current transaction stated below. Do I need to create an extra node just for the sake of transaction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to run some queries on Redshift within  a transaction block but I am a bit skeptical about memory usage of the transaction block. I tried to look into google and AWS forums regarding the memory usage of a transaction block but it did no avail. I want to know the transaction limits in the AWS Redshift.

I am currently using a 2 dc2.large node AWS Redshift cluster which makes the total storage to 320 GB. My requirements need me to run some queries within a transaction block. My transaction block looks like this :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED READ WRITE;
create table bi.test_table as select * from bi.existing_table;
delete from bi.test_table where region = 'ROI';
insert into bi.test_table values (6543,'Vabville','asdRon','2019-04-03 12:10:43',12458860328121043);
update bi.transaction_region_master set city = 'UpdatedCity' where sno = 6543;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

There are multiple such queries which I need to run in one go in a sequence on whole Redshift DWH. I am running the queries from a python script using psycopg2 library. The current Disk Usage of the cluster is 72%. My daily incremental data will be around 5 GB while the existing data in the cluster will be 250 GB. The total capacity of the cluster is 320 GB as stated above. Can I run the queries in a single transaction block or I need to break down the queries into multiple blocks and keep track of them ? Whether the snapshot before committing a transaction is kept within the Redshift cluster (using the same 320 GB of space) or is there some another storage kept aside by AWS itself for these transactions ?

EDIT : Here are my cluster specifications :
Current Node Type     -    dc2.large
CPU                   -    7 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores) per node
Memory                -   15.25 GiB per node
Storage               -   160GB SSD storage per node
I/O Performance       -   Moderate
Platform              -   64-bit

Comment: how many deletes/interts/updates within a transaction? max? can you use the more conventional route of python->s3->copy command->redshift?

Comment: I do not want to load data from S3 to Redshift but do some data manipulation tasks within Redshift tables. Those data manipulation tasks will be required to run over all the tables within the Redshift DWH.